# Javascript: Making a functional calculator

Tags: javascript, calculator

Everything works well but the equals sign do not work. Does anyone know why and how to fix it? I am wondering why the eval('=') won't work in this case.

```js
function calcu(calcValue) {
  if (calcValue == '1') {
    calc.output.value = '1';
  } else if (calcValue == '2') {
    calc.output.value = '2';
  } else if (calcValue == '3') {
    calc.output.value = '3';
  } else if (calcValue == '+') {
    calc.output.value = '+';
  } else if (calcValue == '4') {
    calc.output.value = '4';
  } else if (calcValue == '5') {
    calc.output.value = '5';
  } else if (calcValue == '6') {
    calc.output.value = '6';
  } else if (calcValue == '-') {
    calc.output.value = '-';
  } else if (calcValue == '7') {
    calc.output.value = '7';
  } else if (calcValue == '8') {
    calc.output.value = '8';
  } else if (calcValue == '9') {
    calc.output.value = '9';
  } else if (calcValue == '*') {
    calc.output.value = '*';
  } else if (calcValue == '') {
    calc.output.value = '';
  } else if (calcValue == '0') {
    calc.output.value = '0';
  } else if (calcValue == '/') {
    calc.output.value = '/';
  } else // <-- Notice no condition on this last else
  {
    calc.output.value = eval('='); // <-- the eval() function turns the collection of string into a working math function
  }
}
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it to make a [mcve] - add calc to the code and show the result

Comment: `calc.output.value = eval('=');` does nothing. Did you expect it to do something?

Comment: Yes, it should evaluate the two strings.

Comment: What two strings. you do not have two strings

Comment: And the whole function could be a one liner so far: `calc.output.value = ["0123456789-*/"].includes(calcValue) ? calcValue :  eval('=')`

Comment: Perhaps you mean `calcValue = "2+2"; console.log(eval(calcValue))`